# Error trying to install a npm package from git instead npm repository

Tags: node.js, github, npm

Package I having problems with is:
node-mbus.

In package.json:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "node-mbus": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

It get node_modules from repository and install them in node_modules folder.

but if do:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "node-mbus": "https://github.com/Apollon77/node-mbus"
  }
```

Wiht next error:
npm ERR! make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/obj.target/libmbus/libmbus/mbus/mbus-protocol-aux.o', needed by 'Release/obj.target/mbus.a'.  Stop.

However, If I try to do it with any other package, xml2js, for example:
In package.json:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "xml2js": "latest"
  }
```

Or:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "xml2js": "https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js"
  }
```

Work them both.
So, it doesn't seem to be an error on dependencies url.

why does it work with node-mbus, but it doesn't with url?

### update:

It works too if I clone repository and launch:

```
npm i file:<project-cloned-location>
```

Or if I get it without init scripts:

```
npm i --ignore-scripts https://github.com/Apollon77/node-mbus
cd node_modules/node-mbus
node-gyp configure; node-gyp build
```

---

### SOLVED:

The package.json had next scripts:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "rm -rf libmbus && git clone -b build-windows --single-branch https://github.com/Apollon77/libmbus.git libmbus && rm libmbus/.gitignore && cp config.h libmbus/config.h",
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --exit",
    "release": "release-script"
  },
...
```

And npm was trying to compile libmbus before download, so changing "prepare" by "preinstall" worked:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "rm -rf libmbus && git clone -b build-windows --single-branch https://github.com/Apollon77/libmbus.git libmbus && rm libmbus/.gitignore && cp config.h libmbus/config.h",
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --exit",
    "release": "release-script"
  },
...
```

Comment: `node-xml2js` doesn't need any node-gyp native build and includes the transpiled JS output [in the repo](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/tree/master/lib).

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe.
The example of node-xml2js is to demonstrate that I'm not writting in a bad way the url of repository when I install it from github instead npm-repository.
What I don't understand is the difference between node-mbus from node-repository and node-mbus from github, and why the first one works and the last one, doesn't.